# OpenGL: Depth Stencil buffer won't write underlying texture attached

Tags: c++, opengl, emulation

I'm currently developing an emulator and I got some games using GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 (D24S8) as depth buffer. The depth buffer works fine and all but the underlying texture does not seem to be written. I've checked everything: Write mask, attachment being Depth_Stencil, etc. Still it won't write the underlying texture. It's actually interesting because while rendering the depth buffer, the depth test works, what doesn't work is writting the underlying texture. NSight assumes my texture as it were 2 textures (you can see in the pics), one is allocated to the depth buffer which is correct and the other is the one used later on pixel shader sampling. For some reason it won't write it. Things I checked:

- Framebuffer has the texture attached as a Depth Stencil Attachment.
- Depth Write is on when it's supposed to be.
- There are no copies, reuploads of the texture.
- Stencil mask is well set, everything on keep but stencil test is disabled.

Some extra info:

- I used immutable storage to allocate the depth/stencil buffer.
- Components set to GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8

Things I've tried:

- Flushing after draw and reupload, didn't work, texture had full zeroes.
- glCopyImageSubData to another and use another, didn't work
- Changing it to D32F does not work either, even though NSight shows it does, Renderdocs doesn't.

[image: State when drawing the buffer]

[image: Depth Buffer as seen in Nsight]

[image: The same depth buffer copy created by NSight when sampling later on a pixel shader]

Comment: I know literally nothing about this topic, but I'm going to ask anyways: Can we see the code?

Comment: Aye, edit in a [mcve].

Comment: Sadly with emulation it's pretty hard bring a minimal example. The codebase is public and can be found here: https://github.com/yuzu-emu/yuzu/tree/master/src/video_core the code that does all the above is in opengl_backend/gl_rasterizer.cpp Sadly without the emulation mechanisms the problem is not easily reproducible.

Comment: How do you know that writing to the texture isn't happening? From those screenshots alone, I couldn't tell that.

Comment: I flushed it and look in memory.